# Cannot save and restore a nested Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-orientation, android-nested-fragment

I have a nested Fragment that I am trying to restore the state given an orientation change.

So firstly my setup is as follows:

```
Activity -> ParentFragment (SetRetainInstance(true)) -> ChildFragment
```

In My Child fragment I have the onSaveInstance code as follows:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    // Serialize the current dropdown position.
    outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM, getActivity().getActionBar()
            .getSelectedNavigationIndex());
}
```

However when I orientate the device in all the LifeCycle events return a savedInstance state of null.

Am I doing this incorrectly for a ChildFragment? Why is my state not getting saved and returned?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's due to `setRetainInstance(true)` of your parent fragment. Android retains a fragment with all its children fragments. So your ChildFragment is not destroyed, and that's why you get null in savedInstanceState. The documentation of [onCreateView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20android.os.Bundle)) states:

> *savedInstanceState*  If non-null, this fragment is being re-constructed from a previous saved state as given here.

You can try to comment `setRetainInstance(true)` out and ensure you get correct value for savedInstanceState.

Comment: Yes, but two years ago. :) Maybe something has changed since then.